# Pycharm does not auto suggest spark dataframe methods

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I have been using Spark Scala for a long time, new to PySpark.

I am trying to setup PyCharm for a spark project. Everything is setup from a dependencies point of view (pip install spark for e.g.). I can create a new python file and write spark code, everything is resolved. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate()
data = spark.sql ('select * from db.tbl')
```

At this point should I expect data to be a DataFrame? When I type data. I expect PyCharm to tell me the possible methods like filter, join etc as a drop down, but it does not.

Is there anything more I need to do for this to work? I am using python 2.7 (have to, since that's what our hadoop cluster supports)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, variables are dynamically typed so you declare them without their types.
But starting from Python 3.6+, you can declare the variable type like this :

```
data : DataFrame = spark.sql ('select * from db.tbl')
```

This way you let PyCharm know what is the type of `data` and will suggest possible methods for that object.

[image]

Comment: thx!! That does work, unfortunately I have to use python 2.7. Updated my post. Do I have any options with 2.7?